# Condition for subqueries columns in SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

I am executing a SQL query with sub queries and in that I want condition greater than zero of that subqueries.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT Ledger.Grup,
       ledger.CompanyName,
       ledger.City,
       ledger.ContactNo,
       (ISNULL((SELECT SUM(ConditionFine)
                FROM tbl_Billing
                WHERE partyid = ledger_id
                  AND partytype = 'GOLD'
                  AND CrDr = 'CR'
                  AND AccountMode = 'ESTIMATE'
                  AND BranchId = 13), 0)
           - ISNULL((SELECT SUM(ConditionFine)
                     FROM tbl_Billing
                     WHERE partyid = ledger_id
                     AND partytype = 'GOLD'
                     AND CrDr = 'DR'
                     AND AccountMode = 'ESTIMATE'
                     AND BranchId = 13), 0))
            AS GoldFine,
       (ISNULL((SELECT SUM(ConditionFine)
                FROM tbl_Billing
                WHERE partyid = ledger_id
                  AND partytype = 'SILVER'
                  AND CrDr = 'CR'
                  AND AccountMode = 'ESTIMATE'
                  AND BranchId = 13), 0)
           - ISNULL((SELECT SUM(ConditionFine)
                     FROM tbl_Billing
                     WHERE partyid = ledger_id
                     AND partytype = 'SILVER'
                     AND CrDr = 'DR'
                     AND AccountMode = 'ESTIMATE'
                     AND BranchId = 13), 0))
           AS SilverFine,
       (ISNULL((SELECT SUM(AfterTax)
                FROM tbl_Billing
                WHERE partyid = ledger_id
                  AND CrDr = 'CR'
                  AND AccountMode = 'ESTIMATE'
                  AND BranchId = 13), 0)
           - ISNULL((SELECT SUM(AfterTax)
                     FROM tbl_Billing
                     WHERE partyid = ledger_id
                     AND CrDr = 'DR'
                     AND AccountMode = 'ESTIMATE'
                     AND BranchId = 13), 0))
           AS Amount
FROM   
    tbl_Billing billing
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    tbl_Ledger ledger ON ledger.Ledger_ID = billing.partyid
WHERE  
    billing.BranchID = 13
    AND Ledger.CompanyName IS NOT NULL
    AND AccountMode = 'ESTIMATE'
```

Now, according to this query I want Goldfine > 0, SilverFine > 0, Amount > 0 i.e. if any of these three columns value is greater than 0 then show condition row data else if these columns is equal to 0 then that row don't want to show.

Comment: Sample data and expected results would help immensely. I very much doubt you need those subqueries at all, there is almost certainly a better way to do this.

Comment: You can wrap everything up as a subquery and apply the condition to your outer query. Something like `SELECT * FROM (inner query here) Q WHERE (Q.Goldfine > 0 OR Q.SilverFine > 0 OR Q.Amount > 0)`.

Comment: @TN: or you could just repeat those expression used for `Goldfine`, `Silverfine` and `Amount` in your where clause ... 

Comment: You can also likely restructure your query to use `GROUP BY` and *conditional aggregation* to eliminate that many current subqueries.  Something like `SELECT ..., SUM(CASE WHEN partytype = 'GOLD' AND CrDr = 'CR' THEN ConditionFine ELSE 0 END) - SUM(CASE WHEN partytype = 'GOLD' AND CrDr = 'DR' THEN ConditionFine ELSE 0 END) AS GoldFine, .... GROUP BY Ledger.Grup, ledger.CompanyName, ledger.City, ledger.ContactNo`.  That would then be wrapped up in the subquery as previously suggested.

Comment: @Luuk - I would recommend against repeating complex expressions like that when a single occurrence will do. Easier to read. Easier to maintain. Less prone to bugs caused by typos.

Comment: @TN Your syntax is work. Thank you.

Comment: @Luuk - Just realized that your earlier comment was a joke. (I guess I needed someone to hold up the sarcasm sign.)

Answer (score 2):

If you combine the subselect & conditional suggestion, *conditional aggregation*, and also add a `CROSS APPLY` to convert the `CrDr` column to a sign (+1 or -1), I believe your query can be simplified down to the following.

```
SELECT Q.*
FROM (
    SELECT
        L.Grup,
        L.CompanyName,
        L.City,
        L.ContactNo,
        ISNULL(SUM(
            CASE WHEN L.partytype = 'GOLD'
            THEN L.ConditionFine * S.CrDrSign
            END
            ), 0) AS GoldFine
        ISNULL(SUM(
            CASE WHEN L.partytype = 'SILVER'
            THEN L.ConditionFine * S.CrDrSign
            END
            ), 0) AS SilverFine
        ISNULL(SUM(AfterTax * S.CrDrSign), 0) AS Amount
    FROM tbl_Billing B
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_Ledger L
        ON L.Ledger_ID = B.partyid
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT
           CASE L.CrDr
               WHEN 'CR' THEN 1
               WHEN 'DR' THEN -1
           END AS CrDrSign
    ) S
    WHERE B.BranchID = 13
    AND L.CompanyName IS NOT NULL
    AND L.AccountMode = 'ESTIMATE'
    GROUP BY
        L.Grup,
        L.CompanyName,
        L.City,
        L.ContactNo
) Q
WHERE (
    Q.Goldfine > 0
    OR Q.SilverFine > 0
    OR Q.Amount > 0
)
```

I took the liberty of shortening the table aliases, but you of course can modify and reformat to your preferences.

The subselect can also be moved to a CTE as Peter B suggested. The meaning and execution are identical.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite as (untested):

```
 select 
   Ledger.Grup, 
   ledger.CompanyName, 
   ledger.City, 
   ledger.ContactNo, 
   sum(CASE WHEN partytype='GOLD' 
            THEN CASE WHEN CrDr='CR' THEN ConditionFine 
                      WHEN CrDr='DR' THEN -ConditionFine END 
            END) as GoldFine,
   sum(CASE WHEN partytype='SILVER' 
            THEN CASE WHEN CrDr='CR' THEN ConditionFine 
                      WHEN CrDr='DR' THEN -ConditionFine END 
            END) as SilverFine,
   sum(CASE WHEN CrDr='CR' THEN AfterTax
            WHEN CrDr='DR' THEN -AfterTax
       END) as Amount

from tbl_Billing billing 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_Ledger ledger ON ledger.Ledger_ID = billing.partyid 
where billing.BranchID = 13 
  and Ledger.CompanyName is not null 
  and AccountMode = 'ESTIMATE' 
GROUP BY
   Ledger.Grup, 
   ledger.CompanyName, 
   ledger.City, 
   ledger.ContactNo;
```

Comment: I hope you don't mind - I tweaked your Amount calculation.

Comment: @TN: too much copy/paste..... 

Answer (score 0):

An easy way would be with a [Common Table Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql) so you don't need to repeat the calculations:

```sql
WITH MyCTE
AS (
   ... put your query here ...
)
SELECT *
FROM   MyCTE
WHERE  Goldfine > 0 OR SilverFine > 0 OR Amount > 0
```